# Reporting software for a huge database that has 20 millions of records

Tags: reporting

Is there any reporting or BI that could generate and preview instantly on a huge database? Imagine I will create a report that will get data on single table that has 20 millions record.
What I would like in a reporting or BI is that it should only get data in database that a single page or document needed so that it could show it to the end user immediately and do the other page on the background. Also, when navigating between pages, it should dispose the pages wisely so that it will not leave in the memory. Imagine if the report has 10000 pages (i know this is not practical) but on the end user they didn't know the actual number of pages.

Answer (score 1):

[DBxtra](http://www.dbxtra.com/) is able to generate reports from big databases and it's able to create the first page of the report quickly and generate the rest of them in the background. But honestly, more than 1,000 pages reports are not practical unless you plan to put them on storage for later audits.